# In Magento 2 How to use CSS Grid in CMS pages

Tags: magento2, module, luma-theme

I'm trying to migrate my site casafoca dot ro to M2. And Want my site something like this one - https://banbayu.com/

I especially loved the

1. Responsiveness,
2. Full width of the pictures and
3. css grid wireframe they used in two easily visible sections on the Home Page (cms).

I am using **Porto theme which is bootstrap integrated**  so using bootstrap I can keep the code as clean as possible while also adapting the layout to my needs. Here is my [website URL](http://cf.dev.thedt.com) where I am trying to modify the design/layout.

A friend copied an example of the grid for me in order for me to adapt it and use it and I've been brain-storming ever since. https://jsfiddle.net/8td3hdgL/

I tried using the crappy wysiwyg editor but it doesn't even align two blocks on top of each other, and since I also want to include YouTube embedding in one of the tabs, I've no idea if it will handle it / scale it correctly.

Do you know of a way for the Grid to be implemented in the Wysiwyg editor ?
like adding Grid layout, images , video and slider etc.

Also , how to position grid  in CMS pages like homepage, and using product sliders parallax effect, video or any other content

I want Sequencing the grid like First Images then videos afterward product sliders on home page

And last one how to modify .less files and XML update

Comment: summarize your question for better understanding.... if you use bootstrap then you can easily modify any CMS page layout , as they are static

Comment: I had a huge post that i was unable to post because it was identified as spam, with many chapters. I did mention that i only installed bootstrap, according to a guide (https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29004514/How-to-include-Bootstrap-style-to-magento-2-store.html). I don't really know how to check if it installed correctly, could you instruct me? And i don't know how to modify the CMS layout with a grid myself, not sure which .less files go where or cover what. I would like to modify a) home page b) categories pages for starters. Without  CMS, i would prefer an xml layout update..

Comment: simply inspect in your browser , and check bootstrap classes in css are present or not... or pass the url ..I do for you

Comment: http://cf.dev.thedt.com/ is my current workstation. I for one installed the bootstrap as explained above (by creating that default_head_blocks.xml). I also installed the Porto theme that has bootstrap by itself. So technically it is installed from two sources. Pls advise how to further customize my layout update xml if possible. I'm extremely grateful for your support!

Comment: Bootstrap is installed , you want to change home page ...? if you know how to write page code with bootstrap classes and HTMl then.. do that and create blocks which you can display any where

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming that. Could you also tell me how and where to copy that code from the https://jsfiddle.net/8td3hdgL/ in order to adapt it to my needs? Can the code simply be put in the layout xml update of Content->pages->home page edit-> design ? And managed from there? (i can update my images manually in the server and simply change the url addresses as well as procentages of each image in the grid). Or is it more complicated? Do i need to build a custom module? This is the part that i was stuck with.

Comment: I don't really know how to write code yet, i'm just starting out with basic html functions (and haven't gotten to css yet). I will learn later in time, but for now i need to design this as best as currently possible before re-launch. I have only front-end experience in magento (more in 1 than in 2 tbh)

Comment: Do not deep into complications , its very simple .. Simply Copy HTML from js fiddle and paste in your homepage content and respective CSS in your css file.

Comment: Tomorrow I will tell you more simplified way, Today I gotta leave for the day

Comment: thank you very much, i'll try to look for the .less file responsible for the home page and update it! Have a wonderful day! (you can add me on skype as casafoca1992 if you want).  Namaskar~~

Comment: I've been trying for a few hours to find the correct .less / css files to modify for "home page layout" and "category layout" in order to make those css changes, but without result so far. I've gotten as far as /web/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/layout    since the child theme doesn't really have any files, so i need to modify the parent theme... but i can't find the right files yet.  Is there a way to see what files to modify by inspecting my working station "home page" http://cf.dev.thedt.com/? I'll be counting on some assistance here :) Thank you very much!